# What is bash analog of cmd START /D with nohup?

Tags: bash, process

I want to start a process (from bash script) whose executable is inside current directory, in another directory `$dir` (`nohup` analog for windows `cmd` `START /D`). How to do such thing in bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the process to execute from `$dir`, just do:

```
( cd $dir; ~-/cmd)
```

where `cmd` is the name of the executable in the current directory you wish to execute.  The parentheses cause the two commands to run in a subshell so that your current shell does not change directory, and the `~-` references the previous directory.  Using `~-` is not necessary if your current directory is in your `PATH`, and you may prefer to use a full path instead.  Note that it is generally considered bad practice to put `.` in your `PATH`.

Comment: it would look like `nohup ( cd $dir; ~-/cmd --arg1="2")`?

Comment: or `( cd $dir; nohup ... )` to put the output file in `$dir`